# model not following PrimaryPart

Tags: roblox

Im new to Roblox coding so I am currently following a book. I did the tutorial where a Pet follows the player for X seconds after being pet (proximity prompt). It uses a part that acts as the RootPart which moves torwards the player and the model must follow. I followed all steps and the RootPart moves, but the model stays behind.

video: https://streamable.com/bgmnfg

here is my code:

```
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")

local FOLLOW_DURATION = 10

local Pet = {}
Pet.__index = Pet

function Pet.new(model)
    local self ={}
    setmetatable(self, Pet)
    
    self._model = model
    self._model.Parent = workspace
    
    self._petPrompt = Instance.new("ProximityPrompt")
    self._petPrompt.ObjectText = "Pet"
    self._petPrompt.ActionText = "Pet me!"
    self._petPrompt.RequiresLineOfSight = false
    self._petPrompt.Parent = model.PrimaryPart
    self._petPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function (player)
        self:getPets(player)
    end)
    
    return self
end


function Pet:getPets(player)
    self._petPrompt.Enabled = false
    
    for i=0, FOLLOW_DURATION, 0.25 do
        
        local character = player.Character
        
        if character and character.PrimaryPart then
            
            self._model.Humanoid:MoveTo(character.PrimaryPart.Position)
            
            
        end
        
        wait(0.25)
        
    end
    
    self._petPrompt.Enabled = true
    
    return Pet
end

local Dragon = Pet.new(ServerStorage.PetDragon:Clone())
local Block = Pet.new(ServerStorage.PetBlock:Clone())
```

I have tried anchoring, disabling canCollide, parenting one part to another, ... but it still doesn't work.